# Back propagation algorithm of Neural Network : XOR training

Tags: matlab, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

```
 c=0;
 wih = .1*ones(nh,ni+1);
 who = .1*ones(no,nh+1);

 while(c<3000)
     c=c+1;
     for i = 1:length(x(1,:))


        for j = 1:nh
            netj(j) = wih(j,1:end-1)*double(x(:,i))+wih(j,end)*1;
            outj(j) = 1./(1+exp(-1*netj(j)));
        end

% hidden to output layer

        for k = 1:no

            netk(k) = who(k,1:end-1)*outj+who(k,end)*1;
            outk(k) = 1./(1+exp(-1*netk(k)));
            delk(k) = outk(k)*(1-outk(k))*(t(k,i)-outk(k));

        end

% backpropagation
        for j = 1:nh
            s=0;
            for k = 1:no
                s = s+who(k,j)*delk(k);
            end

            delj(j) = outj(j)*(1-outj(j))*s; 

            s=0;
        end


        for k = 1:no
            for l = 1:nh
                who(k,l)=who(k,l)+.5*delk(k)*outj(l);
            end
            who(k,l+1)=who(k,l+1)+1*delk(k)*1;
        end

        for j = 1:nh
            for ii = 1:ni
                wih(j,ii)=wih(j,ii)+.5*delj(j)*double(x(ii,i));
            end
            wih(j,ii+1)=wih(j,ii+1)+1*delj(j)*1;

        end



    end

end
```

This implements a backpropagation neural network. `x` is input, `t` is desired output, `ni`, `nh`, `no` number of input, hidden and output layer neuron. I am testing this for different functions like AND, OR, it works fine for these. But XOR is not working.

Training `x = [0 0 1 1; 0 1 0 1]`
Training `t = [0 1 1 0]`

`who` = weight matrix from hidden to output layer

`wih` = weight matrix from input to hidden layer

Can you help ?

Comment: I suggest you edit yor question so that it is answerable. It contains no specifics: "I have implemented back propagation algorithm in MATLAB" - perhaps you should start by posting it.

Comment: I have added the code,  let me know if it requires more explanation. I should now expect some feedback from you guys

Comment: You initialize the weights all to the same value. Are you sure this is ok? I am not sure, but I guess this is a bad idea, it might be that the network is constraint by symmetry like this.

Comment: Yes you are right. I remember (about 2 years ago) the problem was solved by random initialization of weights. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

The difference between XOR and all the other functions you describe is that the XOR function is *not* linearly separable.

What may be happening is that you are using linear units (linear activation functions) instead of sigmoidal units (nonlinear activation function).  Additionally, are you certain that you have a hidden layer?

Please post your network topology (briefly), and the type of unit at each layer.

Comment: Yes, there is hidden layer, one input one hidden and one output layer, I am using sigmoid activation and I can change number of neurons in hidden layer, Input layer dimension 2, output is 1, as is for XOR, in hidden layer I am trying different number of neurons but none is working. I think I will include the code